# Mocking a method that edits the input

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to mock a dao method that creates a record then sets the id on the input.

here is some psuedo code

sample test

```
RecordDto input = new RecordDto();
input.setId(null);
input.setName("test");

when(dao.createRecord(any(RecordDto.class)).thenReturn(1);

createSomething(input);
```

method to mock

```
public int createRecord(RecordDto input) {
   int updatedRowCount = 0;
   int primaryKey = db call to create record
   rows += primary != null ? 1 : 0;
   input.setId(primaryKey) <-
   return updateRowCount;
}
```

class under test

```
public void createSomething(RecordDto input)
   int rowsUpdated = dao.createRecord(input);
   if (input.getId() != null) {
      do something <- this code can not be reached from my test
      because my mock only sets the return value. It needs to also
      modify the input.id.
   }
```

Once the method is called in my real class input has an id. My mock just returns a 1 for the row count but the id is still null.

Comment: If `getId` is returning `null` then check when it's assigned, in the `createRecord` method.  It sounds like the database call is returning `null`.

Comment: I didn't explain it well. let me reword my question. I reworded my psuedo code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are **only mocking** the **value return** but **not the side effect** inside the **dao method**. You are passing the `RecordDto` as parameter, doing something and also calling methods that modify the state of the parameter received. The solution for that would be to use `doAnswer` that lets you not only return a value, you can add some extra logic. So, your test should look like this:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    dao = mock(Dao.class);
    RecordDto input = new RecordDto();
    Integer someRandomId = 15;
    Integer randomRowsUpdated = 3;
    Answer<Integer> answer = new Answer<Integer>() {
        public Integer answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
            RecordDto input = invocation.getArgument(0, RecordDto.class); // get the argument received in `createRecord`
            input.setId(someRandomId); // set the new id
            return randomRowsUpdated; // the value to be returned by `createdRecord`
        }
    };
    doAnswer(answer).when(dao).createRecord(input); // using doAnswer instead of doReturn
    createSomething(input);
}
```

That would be the quick solution.

I would say that this is not exactly the best approach. Doing side effects inside a method could cause bugs in a future and it will hard to know the root cause of the problem or even debug. Returning a `RecordDto` or another custom object that lets you now the new id and the affected rows or something similar will make your tests easier to setup and also make the assertion.

Comment: Thanks. This was what I was looking for. Hadnt used thenAnswer before.

Answer (score 0):

If you require some additional mocking behavior other than simply returning a value, you can use `thenAnswer` instead of `thenReturn` in your `when` mocking stub.

I hope this (overly) simplified example helps:

```java
   @Mock
   private Bar executor;

   @Test
   public void testMutation() {
      Foo foo = new Foo();

      when(executor.mutate(foo)).thenAnswer(a -> {
         int mockedId = 10;
         Foo input = a.getArgument(0);
         input.setId(mockedId); // mutate the parameter from the method signature
         return mockedId;
      });

      executor.mutate(foo);
      Assertions.assertEquals(10, foo.getId());
   }

   //---- boiler plate code of the DTO and method that mutates the value
   public class Bar {

      public int mutate(Foo input) {
         input.setId(3);
         return 3;
      }
   }

   public class Foo {
      private int id;

      public int getId() {
         return id;
      }

      public void setId(int id) {
         this.id = id;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. The thenAnswer examples I came across didn't address how to handle side effects of mocking an input mutation.